# Bit Flag dependencies in Sulley Fuzzing Framework

Tags: python, network-protocols, penetration-testing, fuzzing

I'm trying to build a Fuzzer with Sulley. The protocol I'm using has a one byte `control` field. the bits which are set in this field determine which fields can follow. Now I'm wondering how to implement this behaviour using the `dep` parameters in Sulley. The only `dep_compare` operators available are `"==, !=, >, >=, <, <="`, but I don't think I can check whether a bit is set in another field with those operators. So how could I do this?

```
s_byte(0b1000000, "control_field")

# The following block shall be present if bit 7 is set in control_field
# I'd like to use something like 
# > control_field & 0b1000000 != 0 
# but I don't know how

if s_block_start("something_optional", dep="control_field", dep_compare="?"):
    s_short(0x1234, "optional")
s_block_end()
```

Comment: If you do make the patch yourself, please make a pull request to the project! You'll likely run into a number of such possible improvements if you use the tool for very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check the highest bit, you can use `>=`, since 0b10000000 is just a number.

```
if s_block_start("something_optional", dep="control_field", dep_compare=">=", dep_value=0b10000000):
```

If you want to check lower bits, though, you will need to implement your own operator. In `sulley/blocks.py`, look for the `Block` class and its `render` method. There is a big chunk of if blocks that shouldn't be too hard to modify. E.g.

```
        if self.dep_compare == "&" and self.dep_value & self.request.names[self.dep].value != self.dep_value:
            self.rendered = ""
            return
```